# Fill a specific DatagridView column from another DB table

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

I have a DGV with a column that I want to fill with info from another database, i just want to read the ID and write to the column the name that's associated to that ID. So, i've wrote this:

```
string constring5 = @"Data Source=antonio;Initial Catalog=JurisFrameWorkSPROC;User ID=;Password=";
string Query5 = "select Nome from Advogado where IDAdvogado= '" + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value + "'";
SqlConnection cn5 = new SqlConnection(constring5); /*Ligação à base de dados*/
SqlCommand cmd5 = new SqlCommand(Query5, cn5); /*Declaracao para usar comandos SQL*/
try
{
    cn5.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader read5 = cmd5.ExecuteReader())
    {
          while (read5.Read())
          {
            dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value = (read5["Nome"].ToString());

          }
     }
}
finally
{
     cn5.Close();
}
```

And it works, but only for the 1st Row, but i want it for all the rows!
Rows[e.RowIndex] isn't working here because the sender.

Can anyony help me?
Thak you all

---

I've made it like this

```
  for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string constring5 = @"Data Source=antonio;Initial Catalog=JurisFrameWorkSPROC;User ID=sa;Password=1236540nine";
                string Query5 = "select Nome from Advogado where IDAdvogado= '" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value + "'";
                SqlConnection cn5 = new SqlConnection(constring5); /*Ligação à base de dados*/
                SqlCommand cmd5 = new SqlCommand(Query5, cn5); /*Declaracao para usar comandos SQL*/

                try
                {
                    cn5.Open();
                    {

                        using (SqlDataReader read5 = cmd5.ExecuteReader())
                        {

                            while (read5.Read())
                            {
                                //dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value = (read5["Nome"]);
                                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value = (read5["Nome"]);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    cn5.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

But if i do some kind of search, all the populated columns reached by this code disapear :\

Comment: Are you sure your `SqlCommand` gets more than one row?

Comment: I'm not sure, but i can't figure it out, because i can't replace the CurrentRow for a Row[e.Index] :\

Comment: How can i get all the rows?